# Nested Data in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nested

I might be asking a question that's already been answered, but I cannot find it here or somewhere else. So if you could point out to a thread that explains how to work with UITableVIew and nested data.

In the Core Data, I have Groups and Subscriptions. All Subscriptions belong to a group.
So, first I'm displaying Groups in my TableView and when I click on a Group, I want all it its Subscription to be displayed. Then I want to be able to go back to the Group list.

It is something really common and easy, but I can't find the way to do it.

[EDIT 1] : it is for iOS

Comment: I assume this is for iOS, not for OS X, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry for the lack of info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up a UINavigationController that displays the data from the parent level of the hierarchy, putting a disclosure indicator `(>)` on cells corresponding to groups with one or more subscription. When the user taps the disclosure indicator, you push another table-based view controller on the stack, and give it the subscriptions of the current group to display.

Comment: Ok, so basically, If there are n levels in the data hierarchy, I would need n UITableViewController ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul It is typical to reuse the same controller class (of course you would need `n` instances of it). There is an alternative implementation using [Jon Limjap's tree view controller](http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=566), but the canonical implementation uses one controller instance per hierarchy level.

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to make it work for a couple of days without success. Could somebody throw me a bone here.

Comment: @TDeBailleul I think the best thing would be to start a new question, and post some code with the specific errors that you are getting. Since you've been experimenting with this for a while, I suspect that you already have a table view controller and a view controller for your details. Your root view controller is set to `UINavigationController`, and the table view controller is pushed as the root of the navigation controller. This would get you some partial functionality. Describe what does not work, and you'll get specific answers.